# How to mock a 'new Class()' called in a constructor ES6 - Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, constructor, jasmine, es6-modules, es6-class

I am trying to unit-test with Jasmine my ES6 class called MyClass. It is the following.

```
import SomeOtherClass from '../../someOtherClass';

export default class MyClass {
    constructor(){
        this.someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

The problem is that SomeOtherClass runs some code that produces an error because the data provided is not real. I want to mock that class and not being called when I make a new MyClass() in the unit tests. I have tried so many things but nothing works. Some of them are

```
sinon.createStubInstance(SomeOtherClass)
```

or

```
spyOn(NavigationBarComponent.prototype, 'constructor').and.callFake();
```

I try to do that with Jasmine and Sinon.js Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Still no answer to my question. However, for those that might have similar problem Jest provides a way to do that. More info here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

Comment: I think typically if you wanted to mock a dependency then you'll want to inject that dependency and give the test control over injecting it's own dependencies.  So the constructor is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

I think typically if you wanted to mock a dependency then you'll want to inject that dependency and give the test control over injecting it's own dependencies.  So the constructor is an easy way to do that.

```
export default class MyClass {
    constructor(someOtherClassInstance){
        this.someOtherClass = someOtherClassInstance;
    }
}
```

Now your test can provide it's stub or mocked instance when it instantiates `MyClass`.